# Prove K is a normal subgroup of An for some integer n

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I am given a set K with some given values and want to show that it is a normal subgroup of An for some given integer n. Is this how i prove it?
First prove K is a subgroup of An
Second prove that An/K exists and show all its distinct cosets.
Therefore K is normal in An.
Is that it or do I have to show something else as well or use a contradiction?
Thankyou

Comment: The quotient always exists. Normality of $K$ just ensures that the multiplication from $A_n$ carries over to the quotient to make it a group. You should look up the definition of normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show first $K \leq A_n$. Then to show $K \lhd A_n$, you have to prove that $xKx^{-1} \subseteq A_n$ for all $x \in A_n$

$\lhd$ means $K$ is normal subgroup of $A_n$

Comment: for each x and k? because i am given all values of K and An. isn't that going to be too tedious?

Comment: just pick an element in $xKx^{-1}$, and show this element is also in $K$.

Comment: okz thanks a lot for ur help!